# Xcode 5 Custom Assistant Editor

Tags: xcode, plugins

I am trying to figure out how to create a custom assistant editor plugin for Xcode.

My eventual goal is to be able to display Lua (well, a variant of Lua really) byte code line-by-line with the original source code.

Of course where the byte code has more lines to display I would like the main editor window to space out the source code while the assistant is open to keep the lines matched up (like how the diff viewer works).

I have found a bunch of plugins for Xcode 4, and some updated for 5, but none of them do anything with the assistant editors.

Does anyone know of any resources I could use towards the end of creating this type of plugin? Thanks!

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out?

Comment: Sadly, no, instead I went with a stand-alone program to achieve my goals.